# Upload de imagem

Tags: php, html, imagem, upload

como posso fazer o upload de uma imagem, e depois exibir em outra pagina, sem banco de dados, por exemplo

tenho um formulário na minha pagina "inicial", a pessoa faz o upload da imagem, quando fizer a imagem aparece na pagina "imagens"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wender, você precisará armazenar esta imagem em questão.
Abaixo segue uma simples rotina para o upload:

index.html

```
<form action="exibir.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="img">
 <input type="submit" name="img_ok" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

exibir.php

```
<?php
 if($_POST["img_ok"]) {
  $tempname = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
  $name = uniqid();
  $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["img"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Pega extensão de arquivo e converte em caracteres minúsculos.

  $url_exibir = "/img/".$name.".".$extension; // Caminho para exibição da imagem.      

  $url = "./img"; // Pasta onde será armazenada a imagem.
  if(!file_exists($url)) { // Verifica se a pasta já existe.
   mkdir($url, 0777, TRUE); // Cria a pasta.
   chmod($url, 0777); // Seta a pasta como modo de escrita.
  }

  move_uploaded_file($tempname, $url."/".$name.".".$extension); // Move arquivo para a pasta em questão.
 }
?>

<!-- Exibir imagem de upload -->
<img alt="" title="" src="<?php echo $url_exibir; ?>">
```

**ADICIONADO** - *Para mais de uma imagem segue base para implementação:*

index.html

```
<form action="exibir.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="img[]" multiple><br />
 <input type="submit" name="img_ok" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

exibir.php

```
<?php
    if($_POST["img_ok"]) {

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["img"]); $i++) {
        $tempname = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $name = uniqid();
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["img"]["name"][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Pega extensão de arquivo e converte em caracteres minúsculos.

        $url_exibir[$i] = "/img/".$name.".".$extension; // Caminho para exibição da imagem.      

        $url = "./img"; // Pasta onde será armazenada a imagem.

        if(!file_exists($url)) { // Verifica se a pasta já existe.
            mkdir($url, 0777, TRUE); // Cria a pasta.
            chmod($url, 0777); // Seta a pasta como modo de escrita.
        }

        move_uploaded_file($tempname, $url."/".$name.".".$extension); // Move arquivo para a pasta em questão.
    }

 }
?>

<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($url_exibir); $i++) { ?>
    <!-- Exibir imagem de upload -->
    <img alt="" title="" src="<?php echo $url_exibir[$i]; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Olá Thyago obrigado por me ajudar, a imagem esta sendo enviada corretamente porem não esta sendo exibida, usei o inspecionar elemento, e me parece que esta duplicando a extensão.  
por exemplo

jpg.jpg

<img alt="" title="" src="/img/5622846c0486a.png.png">

outra coisa,  é possível enviar mais de uma imagem? tipo

na pagina exibir.php mostrar uma lista

<ul>
  <li>IMAGEM-1</li>
  <li>IMAGEM-2</li>
  <li>IMAGEM-3</li>
</ul>

Comment: @Wender, testei o código que postei na resposta e funcionou sem duplicação da extensão, ideal seria você analisar o código novamente.

Comment: analisei novamente e esta funcionando certinho Thyago, Muito obrigado! 

como faço pra enviar mais de uma imagem? tentei modificar aqui mais sem sucesso.

Comment: Editei a resposta e inclui a outra situação que pediu no caso de mais de uma imagem, espero que ajude, lembrando que o código pode ser melhorado.

Comment: Muito obrigado! me ajudou muito.