# gravando imagens multiplas na pasta de destino e no banco de dados com php e mysql

Tags: php, html

Tem como eu enviar 5 imagens para a pasta de destino (upload), e ao mesmo tempo já gravar os nomes (img.jpeg) dessas imagens na tabela do Banco de Dados, usando PHP e MySql?

Pois eu tentei usando o mesmo raciocínio de como uso para enviar um único arquivo, e tentei adaptar os arquivos de envio, o upload_serv.php e o form, ficando assim:

Form:

```
        <div align="center" style=" padding:2px; float:left; width:290px; height:auto;">
                <?php
                include '../conexao.php';

                $codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM serv WHERE codigo = '$codigo'");
                $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

                $pasta = '../img_serv/';

                if (isset($_POST['upload'])){
                $check = @$_POST['apagar'];
                foreach($check as $img01){
                $delcheck = mysql_query("UPDATE serv SET img01='' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'") or die (mysql_error()); 
                unlink($pasta.'/'.$img01);

                foreach($check as $img02){
                $delcheck = mysql_query("UPDATE serv SET img02='' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'") or die (mysql_error()); 
                unlink($pasta.'/'.$img02);

                foreach($check as $img03){
                $delcheck = mysql_query("UPDATE serv SET img03='' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'") or die (mysql_error()); 
                unlink($pasta.'/'.$img03);

                foreach($check as $img04){
                $delcheck = mysql_query("UPDATE serv SET img04='' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'") or die (mysql_error()); 
                unlink($pasta.'/'.$img04);

                foreach($check as $img05){
                $delcheck = mysql_query("UPDATE serv SET img05='' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'") or die (mysql_error()); 
                unlink($pasta.'/'.$img05);

                if ($delcheck >= '1'){
                echo 'Imagem deletada com sucesso!';
                }else{
                echo 'Erro ao deletar imagem, tente novamente!';
                }}}}}}}
                ?>

                <?php include 'upload_serv.php'; ?>
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php
                include '../conexao.php';
                $seleciona = "SELECT * FROM serv";
                $queryum = mysql_query($seleciona);
                while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($queryum)){
                $img01 = $_FILES['img01'];                  
                $img02 = $_FILES['img02'];
                $img03 = $_FILES['img03'];
                $img04 = $_FILES['img04'];
                $img05 = $_FILES['img05'];
                }
                ?>
                <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $img01;?>" checked readonly>
                <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $img02;?>" checked readonly>
                <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $img03;?>" checked readonly>
                <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $img04;?>" checked readonly>
                <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $img05;?>" checked readonly>

                <label>Selecione Imagem(ns)</label><br />
                <input type="file" name="img01[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" ><br /><br />
                <input type="file" name="img02[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" ><br /><br />
                <input type="file" name="img03[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" ><br /><br />
                <input type="file" name="img04[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" ><br /><br />
                <input type="file" name="img05[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" ><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">

    </form>
    </div>
```

O arquivo Upload:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

    //INFO IMAGEM   
    $file = $_FILES['img01'];
    $numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    $file = $_FILES['img02'];
    $numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    $file = $_FILES['img03'];
    $numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    $file = $_FILES['img04'];
    $numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    $file = $_FILES['img05'];
    $numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder = '../img_serv';

    //REQUiSITOS
    $permite = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
    $maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

    //MENSAGEM
    $msg = array();
    $errorMsg = array(
    1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o Limite de finido em upload_maxsize',
    2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em Max_file_size',
    3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
    4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo', 
    );

    if($numFile <= 0)
    echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!!';
    else{
    for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
    $name = $file['name'][$i];
    $type = $file['type'][$i];
    $size = $file['size'][$i];
    $error = $file['error'][$i];
    $tmp = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

    $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
    $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

    if($error != 0)
    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
    else if (!in_array($type, $permite))
    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
    else if($size > $maxSize)
    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB!";

    else{
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder."/".$novoNome))             
    $img01 = $_FILES['img01'];
    $img02 = $_FILES['img02'];
    $img03 = $_FILES['img03'];
    $img04 = $_FILES['img04'];
    $img05 = $_FILES['img05'];

    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE serv SET img01 = '$novoNome', img02 = '$novoNome', img03 = '$novoNome', img04 = '$novoNome', img05 = '$novoNome' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'");

    if($update == ''){

    echo "<script language='javascript'>
           window.alert('Erro ao atualizar Imagem!!!');
           </script>";
    }else{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= serv_edit.php'>
          <script language='javascript'>
          window.alert('Imagem atualizada com sucesso!');
          </script>";



    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload realizado com sucesso!";
    else{
    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Ocarreu um erro com o Upload!";

    }}}}}
    ?>
```

Bem é isso ai que eu tenho, se os amigos puderem me ajudar a cadastrar os arquivos de imagens no banco de dados e na pasta de destino simultaneamente, ficarei agradecido.
Abraços a todos, e obrigado pela a atenção.

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste post, tem para envio de 1 e de múltiplas imagens como precisa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92974/upload-de-imagem/ não tem o trecho do envio para o bd mas tá fácil de implementar.

Answer (score 0):

O *input* responsável por selecionar a(s) imagens, normalmente possui o atributo **multiple** para o caso de se desejar que o usuário seja capaz de selecionar mais de 1 ficheiro para aquele formulário, é também possível criar 2 ou mais inputs contento o mesmo atributo *name* com parênteses retos *"[]"* para que os valores sejam lidos como um só *(formam uma array)*.

Normalmente quando a variável _$*FILES* recebe um conjunto em vez de um só ficheiro, os valores são agrupados por ordem ao tipo, em vez de serem agrupados por ficheiros.

**Exemplo:**

```
//Ficheiro unico
<input type="file" name="imagem"/>

print_r($_FILES['imagem']);

Array (
       [name]=>exemplo.png [type]=>image/png [tmp_name]=> /tmp/phptemp [error]=>0 [size]=>420
       )

// Multiplos ficheiros
<input type="file" name="imagem[]" multiple/>

print_r($_FILES['imagem']);

Array (
       [name]=> Array([0]=>exemplo.png [1]=>exemplo1.png 
       [type]=> Array([0]=>image/png [1]=> image/jpeg
       [tmp_name]=> Array([0]=>/tmp/phptemp [1]=> /tmp/phptemp1
       [error]=> Array([0]=> 0 [1]=>0 
       [size]=> Array([0]=> 420 [1]=> 580
       )
```

Com o *php* podes iterar essa array, de modo a obter cada valor e manipular de acordo com o tipo de trabalho.

Para um exemplo simples, farias o seguinte para a parte html:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="file" name="imagem[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="ENVIAR"/>
</form>
```

E para o script *php* terias algo assim:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && !empty($_POST['enviar'])){
    $imagem = isset($_FILES['imagem']) && !empty($_FILES['imagem']) ? $_FILES['imagem'] : NULL;
    // utilizando o $_FILES, a unica relacao existente
    // entre os ficheiros será o numero de indice, visto que  serão agrupados
    // por tipo consoante os indices de $_FILES
    if($imagem){
        $i=0;
        $plain = '';
        // iterando dessa forma, tem-se melhor controle da quantidade de elementos existente nessa array
        foreach($imagem['name'] as $img){
            switch($imagem['type'][$i]){
                case 'text/plain':
                // executar acçao caso formato corresponder
                $plain = 'sou texto simples';
                break;
                case 'image/png';
                // executar acçao caso formato corresponder
                $plain = 'sou imagem png';
                break;
                case 'image/jpg':
                // executar acçao caso formato corresponder
                $plain = 'sou imagem jpg';
                break;
                case 'image/jpeg':
                // executar acçao caso formato corresponder
                $plain = 'sou imagem jpeg';
                break;
                default:
            }
            echo $img . ' - ' . $imagem['size'][$i] . ' - ' . $imagem['type'][$i] . " <b>" . $plain . "</b><br/>";
            $i++;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Selecione um arquivo de imagem primeiro";
    }
}

?>
```

Usando estruturas de controle pode-se capturar erros, o tipo MIME e outros detalhes do(s) ficheiro(s) dentro do loop, como no exemplo acima.

Por exemplo, adicionando a condição à seguir ao *switch*, executamos as instruções passadas, apenas se a condição for verdadeira.

```
case 'image/png';
// executar acçao caso formato corresponder
// Exemplo
$plain = 'sou imagem PNG';
$dados = "Nome:" . $imagem['name'][$i] . "\n";
$dados .= "Nome temporario:" . $imagem['tmp_name'][$i] . "\n";
$dados .= "Tamanho:" . $imagem['size'][$i] . "\n";
$dados .= "Tipo MIME:" . $imagem['type'][$i] . "\n";
$fopen = fopen('assinar.txt','w');
fwrite($fopen, $dados);
fclose($fopen);
break;
```

Isto faz com que escrevamos no ficheiro *assinar.txt* todos os dados referentes aos ficheiros com tipo MIME igual a *image/png*.

Para um exemplo utilizando um banco de dados, seria basicamente a mesma coisa.

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tabela_mysql");
if($con->connect_errno){
    die('Conexao falhou: '. $con->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && !empty($_POST['enviar'])){
    $imagem = isset($_FILES['imagem']) && !empty($_FILES['imagem']) ? $_FILES['imagem'] : NULL;
    if($imagem){
        $i=0;
        $plain = $msg = '';
        $upload = __DIR__.'/upload';
        foreach($imagem['name'] as $img){
            $query = "INSERT INTO imagens(nome) VALUES ('{$imagem['name'][$i]}')";
            if($con->query($query) && move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'][$i], $upload.'/'.$imagem['name'][$i])){
                $msg = "Ficheiros enviados e cadastrados";
            } 
            else {
                $msg = "Erro: falha ao inserir/cadastrar imagens \"" . $con->errno ? $con->error : '';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        echo isset($msg) ? $msg : '';
    } else {
        echo "Selecione um arquivo de imagem primeiro";
    }
}

?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="file" name="imagem[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="ENVIAR"/>
</form>
```

Consultas utilizando *UPDATE* retornam **booleanos** para sucesso, ou falha.

A tua pergunta é sobre *"Como gravar múltiplos ficheiros na pasta de destino e no banco de dados"*, ao ler a parte explicativa achei o mesmo, mas ao ler o *script*, parece que tem mais haver com remoção de arquivos da pasta de destino, e do banco de dados. Contudo, o **UPDATE** não serve para remover, serve para atualizar/modificar valores das tabelas, para remover dados do banco de dados utiliza-se **DELETE**.

> Se a tua dúvida for sobre como carregar múltiplos ficheiros para a pasta de destino e sobre como grava-los ao mesmo tempo no banco de dados, então segue os passos que descrevi, caso contrário, edita a pergunta e tenta explicar melhor sobre o que se baseia o problema.